# Modifying C# Out parameter more than once

Tags: c#, out

When you have a function that has an out parameter is it best practice to create a new variable inside the function and assign the out parameter to it at the end of the function? Or give the out parameter some empty/default value in the beginning and modify throughout the function.

I'm trying to come up with some reasoning as to why one of these coding styles/practices is better to use.

Option 1: Using just the out parameter.

```
public bool SomeFunc(out string outStr)
{
   outStr = "";

   if (errorCond)
      return false;

   outStr += "foo";
   outStr += "bar";

   return true;
}
```

Option 2: Using a temporary variable.

```
public bool SomeFunc1(out string outStr)
{
   string tempStr = "";
   outStr = "";      // To prevent 'The out parameter must be set' error on return false line.

   if (errorCond)
      return false;

   tempString += "foo";
   tempString += "bar";

   outStr = tempStr;
   return true;
}
```

Even though both of these achieve the same outcome, which is preferable? Are there any drawbacks to either one of them?

Comment: Nothing wrong with setting it an using it multiple times. However, I would suggest to use a `StringBuider`, in those cases where you are going to be doing a lot of concatenation at the end of a string.

Comment: Assigning it once does give the just-in-compiler an easier time to optimize the code.  Assignments to an out-parameter are treated volatile since they potentially modify memory.  The odds that you can measure the improvement are not that good, the cost of the string operations are significantly higher.  You only get good guidance from a profiler.

Comment: The first option, because less code in general is better readable.

Comment: Compilers are really smart these days. I bet ``tempStr`` variable would not even be created if you compile code in Release.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it doesn't matter, you just must assign variable in this method. 
But, it is preferable [to avoid using output or reference parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-2.0/ms229053(v=vs.80)):

> Working with members that define out or reference parameters requires
>   that the developer understand pointers, subtle differences between
>   value types and reference types, and initialization differences
>   between out and reference parameters.

For me, the second one is overhead

Assign a default value at the beginning of the method, and then change the value if necessary.

Look at  examples in .net source codes, like [int.TryParse](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/number.cs,1081) or [Enum.TryParse](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/enum.cs,7ef4c46032079d2b)

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the source for some .net functions. It's clear that in the examples they use the first method I pointed out. Your comment about not using `out` parameters provides no help because this question is specifically about `out` parameters.